# TLC555 design calculator

Tags: 555, texas-instruments

I need to generate a square wave at 600 kHz with the TLC555. In the datasheet (7.3.2 Astable Operation) TI advise us to use their [calculation tool](https://www.ti.com/tool/TLC555CALC) for the frequencies above 100 kHz. I downloaded it and I introduced the value in the tool for the calculation: Vcc = 5V, C1 = 0.1n, frequency = 600kHz, duty cycle = 50%, and I checked the box “Use Diode?” (for the ~50% duty cycle).

[image]

After that I introducef the value calculated in a Spice simulation.  I use “PSpice for TI” because it should have the best spice model for the simulation (the encrypted one.)

[image]

[image]

The problem is that the result of the simulation don’t match with the calculation design tool. I don’t understand why. Is my simulation wrong? Is the TI tool’s wrong? Is the model from TI wrong?

Comment: I suggest that you try again but use a larger value for C1, try 1 nF instead of 100 pF. 100 pF is on the edge of what any 555 can support. Also don't use a 1N4007 for D1, the 1N4000 series are **too slow for this**. Use a 1N4148 instead. For a 50% ducy the charging and discharging times of the capacitor should be equal. With the diode in place as shown, the charging is done by R1 and the discharging by R2. So what does that tell us about the values of R1 and R2?

Comment: Also look at this recent question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/583664/50-555-cycle-comparing-two-diagrams  for a much simpler circuit.

Comment: Ok I see, Thank you very much for your answer ! it's help me a lot for understanding my problem ! (I thought that the 4007 is good but I was wrong, so thx !!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should teach you a lesson never to use a 555 in a design for a clock.

[image]

The diode produces an asymmetric pulse for PFM modulation , changing frequency with a pulse width then use CONTROL.

If you want a really simple oscillator use a Schmitt Trigger with precise thresholds. The CMOS type may be close enough at room temp with 1/3 Vdd for the dV/dt then RC may be selected.

### Design Recommendation.

Drop the 555 solution and use any CMOS Schmitt Inverter for room temp operation and choose 71.9% of the RC=T frequency cycle.

Choose R feedback = 11.9k somehow and C = 100 pF NPO preferred 1%
and this [rediculously simple design instead.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/350211/how-to-remove-non-square-noise-from-pierce-oscillator/350220#350220)

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much your answer helps me a lot. You've right I will replace it with the other solution, it's more precise and there is less of problems. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the 555's output is high, C1 is charging via R1 and the diode. Whilst the 555's output is low C1 is discharging only via R2.

R1 is sized smaller than R2 to account for the voltage drop across the diode and the calculator probably assumes that the voltage drop across the diode is 0.7V approx.

At such low C1 charge and discharge currents, the voltage drop across the diode will be quite a bit less than 0.7V which will increase the voltage across R1, increasing the C1 charging current and reducing the duty cycle.

Try adding a second diode as shown below and make R1 = R2. This should even up the C1 charge and discharge currents to give a 50% duty cycle.

[image: 555 oscillator]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! It's help to understand more the problem !!